# I am admin account on Windows 7 and I can't delete certain files or folders no matter what

Tags: windows-7, permissions, administrator

I have Windows 7 Pro, SP1, and I am logged in as "Mark", which is an admin account.  I can check that in the Control Panel "Users" app, that indeed I am admin.

My successful Visual Studio compilation of some extension, created some folders, such as "obj", which are subsequently impossible to remove.

I tried doing it from:
cmd running as Admin,
Cygwin,
Safe Mode,
all failed.

I checked permissions permissions say this account has full access.

In any case, I am also unable to change permissions, and unable to change ownership.

The ownership will not display, it says "unable to display ownership".

The folder in question is "Read-only" in Properties, and I am also unable to uncheck that box and OK.

Same thing holds true for any of the individual files in the folder.

The Administrator account is enabled, the above problems happen whether I log in that account, or my account with Admin privileges.

All these actions result in some variation of "permission denied", "need to be admin", "need to acquire ownership" and such.

I Googled and all of the solutions I found on various fora, including MS, involve some variation of some of the above, and I tried all of them, and noone work.

What else to do?

Comment: First make sure Administrator account is enabled by going to computer management-->Local Users and Groups-->Users-->, right-clicking administrator and going to properties. You should set administrator password. Then log into that account by switching users and logging in as administrator.

Comment: @SergioDominguez  Did not work.  I have enabled the Admin account and logged in to it, but when I try to delete the files, it still says that these files are owned by "Mark" and I need permission from that account.

Comment: I have found this solution online, not sure if it will work but work a try.  
 The issue is with UAC.
You can disable the UAC feature that triggers this.
Start---run---gpedit.msc
Computer Configuration -- windows settings --Security Settings -- Local Policies -- Security Options
Scroll down to:
User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode - Set to DISABLED.
Reboot.
Done.

Comment: @SergioDominguez Yes thank you please make it an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: To whoever downvoted the question, it is not personal, but I would like to know, what prompted you to do so, so I can learn and improve my questions.  Thank you.

Comment: The accepted solution might work but it's *completely* disabling UAC,which is a bad idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088593/how-to-clean-visual-studio-bin-and-obj-folders should be a better solution.

Comment: @HoD Well, I agree with you in general that protections like this are a good idea and disabling them is a bad idea.  In this particular case, admin protections by Microsoft are buggy and broken, I experienced that many times, this one included.

Comment: This "solution" removes the little security Microsoft has managed to add to their OS. This essentially gives ALL your applications like the web browser and everything else, the same rights as the system-administrator... If you can't see that it is a bad idea, then I can tell you it essentially leaves your computer wide open to malware unless all your software is perfect and without bugs... Guess what. The perfect browser doesn't exist... Check how many bug and vulnerabilities Internet Explorer, Edge, Chrome and Firefox get patched every year ;)

Comment: @svin83 Yes I just disabled the feature for a moment, in order to delete the offending stuff, then I enabled the protections back again.  Thank you for the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the UAC feature that triggers this. Start---run---gpedit.msc Computer Configuration -- windows settings --Security Settings -- Local Policies -- Security Options Scroll down to: User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode - Set to DISABLED. Reboot. Done.

Comment: but consider: this is a security feature, you should re-enable it after making the necessary changes! (see Question comments above)